# Messages never arrive in the queue

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I use NServiceBus with MSMQ on Windows Server 2008.
In one of our scenario we send a command to another server queue but sometimes the message never arrives in the queue and MSQM doesn't throw an exception.

I have written a small application that sends a message directly to the queue without NServiceBus and I have encountered the same problem.

I think it isn't a nservicebus problem but a MSMQ problem : windows security, network,...

How can I force MSMQ to return an error when the message can't be saved in queue ?
What are the possible reasons of this behavior ?
Where are the messages that have disappeared ?

Comment: Have you looked in the outgoing queues for the sending server?

Answer (score 1):

In the MSMQ Management snap-in take a look at the system queues and look at transactional dead letter and non-transactional dead letter queues.
Also be sure to have setup queue ACL correctly.